# Server stops responding without any load, restart required

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, web-hosting, performance-tuning

- Sever is working as a very high-traffic application back-end
- We are using Apache2, MySql, and PHP.
- We have already optimized the above for best performance

Server configuration is:

```
Linux server109-228-5-100.live-servers.net 2.6.35-30-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Sun Jun 5 04:00:23 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

4 Virtual CPUs

10GB RAM

160GB HDD

Below is our system log

```
Jan 21 07:51:30 server109-228-5-100 kernel: [94075.247351] VMBUS: Shutdown request received - gracefull shutdown initiated
Jan 19 08:21:50 server109-228-5-100 kernel: [39170.607633] VMBUS: Shutdown request received - gracefull shutdown initiated
Jan 19 22:31:06 server109-228-5-100 kernel: [50921.847444] VMBUS: Shutdown request received - gracefull shutdown initiated
Jan 20 05:43:09 server109-228-5-100 kernel: [25900.745234] VMBUS: Shutdown request received - gracefull shutdown initiated
Jan 18 06:54:40 server109-228-5-100 kernel: [50627.941834] VMBUS: Shutdown request received - gracefull shutdown initiated
Jan 18 12:12:01 server109-228-5-100 kernel: [19021.207225] VMBUS: Shutdown request received - gracefull shutdown initiated
Jan 18 21:28:35 server109-228-5-100 kernel: [33364.786087] VMBUS: Shutdown request received - gracefull shutdown initiated
Jan 17 16:50:24 server109-228-5-100 kernel: [48202.584945] VMBUS: Shutdown request received - gracefull shutdown initiated
Jan 17 03:26:37 server109-228-5-100 kernel: [86905.587588] VMBUS: Shutdown request received - gracefull shutdown initiated
Jan 15 11:02:16 server109-228-5-100 kernel: [25437.193105] VMBUS: Shutdown request received - gracefull shutdown initiated
Jan 16 03:17:47 server109-228-5-100 kernel: [58506.870109] VMBUS: Shutdown request received - gracefull shutdown initiated
```

Can anybody suggests if it is a fault form our server provider?
If yes, how can we overcome this issue?

Please let me know if you need more details from other logs.

Thanks in advance for your valuable time.

PS: By the way, the server provide is Fasthosts from UK. If anybody has a similar experience with them before.

Comment: This is what we found for issue listed above http://antmeetspenguin.blogspot.com/2011/01/detecting-and-preventing-syn-flood.html

Answer (score 1):

The key part of your log file is `VMBUS`, It points to your server provider as suspected.

To overcome the issue, you'd probably have to call them up and ask what the heck is going on - and if that node is problematic, arrange for a transfer to a new node.

I do find it odd that `graceful` is spelled incorrectly - is that verbatim from the log?

Comment: log is copy and past form log file.